# Convert RGB QColor to HSL

Tags: qt, qt5, rgb, hsl, qcolor

code:

```
QColor color = "#f0f0f0";
qDebug() << color;
qDebug() << color.toHsl();
qDebug() << color.convertTo(QColor::Hsl);
```

output:

```
QColor(ARGB 1, 0.941176, 0.941176, 0.941176)
QColor(AHSL 1, -1, 0, 0.941176) // hue == -1 here
QColor(AHSL 1, -1, 0, 0.941176) // hue == -1 here
```

from docs: [QColor::fromHslF()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcolor.html#fromHslF):

> ...
>
> **All the values must be in the range 0.0-1.0.**

Docs for QML side [color hsla()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#hsla-method):

> Returns a color with the specified hue, saturation, lightness, and
> alpha components. **All components should be in the range 0-1
> (inclusive).**

I need to get correct hue, saturation and lightness values on QML side. How to convert such RGB QColor to HSL QColor?

Comment: From the same docs: "Qt returns a hue value of -1 for achromatic colors". What if you try another color value?

Comment: @vahancho yes, hue == -1 only for achromatic colors. I'd fixed that on QML side by forcing `if (color.hue < 0) color.hue = 0`